# Pass local environment variable to docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

This might be a general docker problem but my use-case is docker-compose:

I need to pass my machine's hostname as an environment variable to a container which would be created through docker-compose. That particular container uses a Dockerfile and uses "cmd" flag in it. The command in "cmd" uses this environment variable. Can someone please help?

Comment: answered: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2091

Comment: thanks @dnephin , it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can rewrite the Dockerfile in order to include the hostname in an [`ENV` instruction,](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env) as mentioned in [issue 1136](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1136#issuecomment-127273481), that will work:

```
FROM centos:latest
ENV BLABLA hello
RUN echo $BLABLA 
# outputs: "hello"
```

If this is purely a runtime environment variable value, it should be included in docker 1.9 with [issue 14634: Builder - Build-time argument passing (e.g., `HTTP_PROXY`)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14634):

In the meantime, the [OP 208rishabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3690397/208rishabh) mentions [issue 2091](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2091) for `docker compose`, answered by [dnephin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444646/dnephin):

> environment or env_file [should both work](http://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#environment):
>
> You can leave the value blank, and it will take the value from the current environment:

```
environment:
   HOST_HOSTNAME:
```

That allows:

```
HOST_HOSTNAME=$(hostname) docker-compose up
```

Comment: The first solution would require me to hard code the "value" of the environment variable. I want something dynamic.

The run-time env variable value seems cool :)

For now, the solution is here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2091

Comment: @208rishabh Excellent: I have included your GitHub issue resolution in the answer for more visibility.